# Font awesome icons no longer working in "\f" content values

Tags: font-awesome

I've recently upgraded to font awesome icons 5.1.0.
But now the "\f" methods of putting icons into css content no longer works.

For example:

```
.fc .fc-toolbar .fc-prev-button .ui-icon-circle-triangle-w:before {
    content: "\f00c";
}
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're attempting to use pseudo-elements (the `:before` part of your CSS selector) and setting the contents of those pseudo-elements to the unicode value indicated by `\f00c`.

Pseudo-elements *do* still work in Font Awesome 5.1.0. You'll need to set the correct CSS properties, like `font-family` and `font-weight`, for those elements.

And, if you're using the SVG with JavaScript method, you'll have to configure Font Awesome to enable pseudo-element support. For the Web Fonts with CSS method, pseudo-element support is always intrinsically available.

There are several possibilities, depending on which method you're using and whether you're using Free or Pro. But here's an example of using Web Fonts with CSS, Free:

```
.fc .fc-toolbar .fc-prev-button .ui-icon-circle-triangle-w:before {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

If you're using SVG with JavaScript, make sure your `<script>` tag that loads Font Awesome, includes the `data-search-pseudo-elements` attribute:

```
<script data-search-pseudo-elements ... >
```

See also [documentation here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements) for how to use pseudo-elements in 5.1.0.